# Writing to a specific range/Column with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm attempting to copy from column Range `AP:AR` of workbook 1 to Range `A:C` of workbook 2 through Pandas data frames.

I have successfully read the data frame below in workbook 1, I then want to write this into workbook 2 of the specified range.  So `AP:AR to AQ:AS.`

I have tried:

```
#df.to_excel(writer, 'AP')
```

I have also tried the following:

```
 #df = pd.write_excel(filename, skiprows = 2, parse_cols = 'AP:AR')
pd.writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', columns = 'AP:AR')
pd.writer.save()
```

For example:

```
filename ='C:/ workbook 1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows = 2, parse_cols = 'A:C')

import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/DRAX/ workbook 2.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'AQ')
writer.save()
print(df)
```

It reads correctly, but writes to Cell column ‘B’ instead of AQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the [starting column](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) you want to write the dataframe with the parameter `startcol`, which is an integer starting from 0:

So you should change the line

```
df.to_excel(writer, 'AQ')
```

to

```
df.to_excel(writer, startcol=42) # AQ has the index of 42
```

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Hi @GordonLeclair does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.