# When writing to excel, make columns not at top level

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe e.g `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2]})`

```
    col1
0   1
1   2
```

I want it when I do `df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')`, I get an output with a bit of padding on top e.g.

[image]

So I decided to add empty rows to the top of the dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2]})

empty_rows = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0,1], columns=df.columns)

pd.concat([empty_rows, df])
```

However, this leaves the column name, `col1`, at the top of the excel file when I write to the excel file.

[image]

How can I create the effect like in my first image?

Comment: Try:  `df.to_excel('abc.xlsx', startrow=4)` see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324773/writing-to-a-specific-range-column-with-pandas

Comment: @JonSG thanks for your answer and it is correct for this question I wrote, however my question wasn't super accurate to my problem so I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75437933/when-writing-to-excel-add-padding-on-the-top-of-dataframe-with-meta-info if you could take a look