# When writing to excel, add padding on the top of dataframe with meta info

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe e.g `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2]})`

```
    col1
0   1
1   2
```

I want it when I do `df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')`, I get an output with a bit of padding on top of the entire dataframe, where I write some meta information in that space, i.e

[image]

How can I do this best?

Comment: Start with the `openpyxl` API?

Comment: @BigBen I'd prefer a solution using pandas

Comment: Why? What do you think pandas is using under the hood?

Comment: @BigBen Oh I thought there was a solution with pandas, ill look into excel libraries then

Comment: FWIW, I'm not saying that it's not doable with pandas, it just seems that pandas would be the wrong tool here.